# Daydream Non-VR Mode in Unity 5.4.2f-GVR13

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-vr, daydream

last week I tried to integrate my Unity project to Daydream, the integration went fine.

Now I am trying to seperate the first scenes (which include login process so I need the android soft-keyboard) from the rest of the application - I want the application to open like any android-non-vr application and to switch to VR mode only after the first two scenes.

I read in some answer by Unity staff member that by adding "none" before "Daydream" in the "Virtual Reality Supported" settings the application starts in a non-VR mode.

Virtual Reality Supported settings

[image]

and now I am trying to switch in runtime to VR mode through C# script.

By now I tried to change "VR Mode Enable" of the GvrViewerMain in Runtime but It doesn't switching the application to VR Mode.

Does anyone know how/if it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your minimum api level in build setting to Android 7.0 'Nougat'.

Comment: Just did, still not working out.

Comment: @omriherman Found this inside unity docs. Follow the link https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/VR.VRSettings.LoadDeviceByName.html  . Just pass parameter "daydream" instead of "Split" inside LodeDevice() method.