# Switch VR mode while moving to next scene in Daydream

Tags: unity-game-engine, daydream

I am using daydream sdk in unity 5.6
I have the problem where I want my login scene to be open in non VR mode and once login is successful, open next scene in VR mode. found this [Daydream Non-VR Mode in Unity 5.4.2f-GVR13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41299714/daydream-non-vr-mode-in-unity-5-4-2f-gvr13) but not able to do using it. Not sure how or where to use that code. Can someone help me out?

If I check the "Virtual Reality supported" checkbox, the login scene also opens in VR mode. And if I don't the second scene also opens in non VR mode.

Comment: Added more details to my other answer. Give that a try and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: Thanks that works like a charm.

Comment: Nice. Glad I could help.